# JAX-RS (Jersey) custom exception with XML or JSON

Tags: java, mime, jersey, jax-rs

I have a REST service built using Jersey.

I want to be able to set the MIME of my custom exception writers depending on the MIME that was sent to the server. `application/json` is returned when json is received, and `application/xml` when xml is received.

Now I hard code `application/json`, but that's making the XML clients left in the dark.

```
public class MyCustomException extends WebApplicationException {
     public MyCustomException(Status status, String message, String reason, int errorCode) {
         super(Response.status(status).
           entity(new ErrorResponseConverter(message, reason, errorCode)).
           type("application/json").build());
     }
}
```

What context can I tap into to get the current requests `Content-Type`?

Thanks!

---

### Update based on answer

For anyone else interested in the complete solution:

```
public class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException {

    private String reason;
    private Status status;
    private int errorCode;

    public MyCustomException(String message, String reason, Status status, int errorCode) {
        super(message);
        this.reason = reason;
        this.status = status;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Together with an `ExceptionMapper`

```
@Provider
public class MyCustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyCustomException> {

    @Context
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    public Response toResponse(MyCustomException e) {
        return Response.status(e.getStatus()).
                entity(new ErrorResponseConverter(e.getMessage(), e.getReason(), e.getErrorCode())).
                type(headers.getMediaType()).
                build();
    }
}
```

Where ErrorResponseConverter is a custom JAXB POJO

Comment: What would the ErrorResponseConverter class look like?

Comment: @Oskar: Please show us your implementation of ErrorResponseConverter. Thanks!

Comment: @dreboy It would just be some POJO that will be returned to the user containing the error information.  You would annotate it for Jackson/JAXB/whatever to support various content types.

Comment: @ach I figured it out. Thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try adding a @javax.ws.rs.core.Context javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders field/property to your root resource class, resource method parameter, or to a custom javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper and calling HttpHeaders.getMediaType().

Comment: ExceptionMapper was the way to go. Thanks!

Instead of:
public class MyCustomException extends WebApplicationException

I made a:
public class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException

together with a:
public class MyCustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyCustomException>

that implements:

public Response toResponse(PlacesException e) {
        return Response.status(e.getStatus()).
                entity(new ErrorResponseConverter(e.getMessage(), e.getReason(), e.getErrorCode())).
                type(headers.getMediaType()).
                build();
    }

Answer (score 16):

headers.getMediaType() responds with the media type of the Entity, not the Accept header. The appropriate way to convert the exception is with the Accept header so your client gets the response in the format they requested. Given the above solution, if your request looks like the following (note JSON accept header, but XML Entity), you will get XML back.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/service/giftcard/invoice?draft=true HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjp1c2Vy
Content-Type: application/xml
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: localhost:8080
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 502
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><sample><node1></node1></sample>
```

The correct implementation is again, to use the Accept header:

```
public Response toResponse(final CustomException e) {
    LOGGER.debug("Mapping CustomException with status + \"" + e.getStatus() + "\" and message: \"" + e.getMessage()
            + "\"");
    ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(e.getStatus()).entity(
            new ErrorResponseConverter(e.getMessage(), e.getReason(), e.getErrorCode()));

    List<MediaType> accepts = headers.getAcceptableMediaTypes();
    if (accepts!=null && accepts.size() > 0) {
        //just pick the first one
        MediaType m = accepts.get(0);
        LOGGER.debug("Setting response type to " + m);
        rb = rb.type(m);
    }
    else {
        //if not specified, use the entity type
        rb = rb.type(headers.getMediaType()); // set the response type to the entity type.
    }
    return rb.build();
}
```

Comment: I agree that you should use the Accept: header and not the HttpHeaders.getMediaType(). What I think is ambiguous is simply picking the first one. To me it makes more sense to try to use the one that corresponds the the @Produces annotation of the resource that Jersey matches for the request. Off the top of my head I'm not sure how to wire that up though.

Comment: @domienic-d Actually it appears there's an open JIRA on this very topic https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_RS_SPEC-323 - So in light of that I would say your solution is the best you can do for now.

Comment: JAX_RS_SPEC-323 is no longer available at java.net; this issue has been migrated to: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxrs-api/issues/328