# RestEasy ExceptionMapper NotAllowedException Serialization Error MediaType octet-stream

Tags: rest, resteasy, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I present here the simple rest service to illustrate the exception I receive.

Service **A**

```
@Path("/A")
public class ServiceA {

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response show() {
        return Response.ok(new User("John", "Doe")).build();
    }
}
```

Model:

**User**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**ErrorResponse**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ErrorResponse {

    private String errorType;
    private String errorMessage;

    public ErrorResponse() {
    }

    public ErrorResponse(String errorType, String errorMessage) {
        this.errorType = errorType;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getErrorType() {
        return errorType;
    }

    public void setErrorType(String errorType) {
        this.errorType = errorType;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Finally my **ExceptionMapper** looks like this:

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericExceptionMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(exception.getClass().getSimpleName(), exception.getMessage());

        if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {
            LOG.error("Type: {}", exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
            LOG.error("Message: {}", exception.getMessage());
            WebApplicationException webApplicationException = (WebApplicationException) exception;
            return Response.status(webApplicationException.getResponse().getStatus()).entity(errorResponse).build();
        }

        return Response.serverError().entity(errorResponse).build();
    }
}
```

Calling a GET on the URI I get a correct response:

```
Accept: application/json
GET http://localhost:8080/exception-mapper-example/rest/A

{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
```

However calling POST on this URI I get an exception:

```
 2017-01-13 16:53:46,859 ERROR [com.aizaz.samples.exceptionmapper.GenericExceptionMapper] (default task-35) Type: NotAllowedException
 2017-01-13 16:53:46,860 ERROR [com.aizaz.samples.exceptionmapper.GenericExceptionMapper] (default task-35) Message: RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header
 2017-01-13 16:53:46,860 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-35) UT005023: Exception handling request to /exception-mapper-example/rest/A: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.aizaz.samples.model.ErrorResponse of media type: application/octet-stream
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:180)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:199)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.aizaz.samples.model.ErrorResponse of media type: application/octet-stream
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:66)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:176)
... 32 more
```

**Relevant part**

```
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure:
Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type:
com.aizaz.samples.model.ErrorResponse of media type: application/octet-stream
```

Obviously serialization failed since the media type: application/octet-stream.

I know I can explicitly specify media type when building a response such as

```
 Response.ok().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

But I don't want to do that; since I accept both JSON/XML Accept headers and would like to sent back an appropriate response in JSON or XML format.

1. How can I accomplish this?
2. Why in this case Response is created with media type octet-stream?

I mean if I create my custom exception which is mapped by the same ExceptionMapper as described in the code; the Response object doesn't need to explicitly specify **MediaType**.

Would be really nice if someone can provide me his/her valuable wisdom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of custom exceptions which extend `WebApplicationException` such as

```
public class MyCustomException extends WebApplicationException
```

does not require an explicit `ExceptionMapper<MyCustomerException>` for exception handling and response creation.

ExceptionMapper can be very helpful to handle exceptions which derive from `Exception` (or its subclasses) but not `WebApplicationException` (and its subclasses) (note `WebApplicationException` is also a child class of `Exception`)

For example ExceptionMapper can be used to handle an exception such as `IllegalArgumentException` and creating a response.

In both case above the response can be serialized according to the `@Produces`specified on the Resource method.

However after looking at the spec implementation of RestEasy I found out, the even for `WebApplicationException`(s), if an ExceptionMapper is `@Provided` by the rest service, it will be trigged.

```
resteasy-jaxrs:3.1.0.Final
class: ExceptionHandler
method: public Response handleException(HttpRequest request, Throwable e)

  // First try and handle it with a mapper
  if ((jaxrsResponse = executeExceptionMapper(e)) != null) {
     return jaxrsResponse;
  }
```

So either I make sure that ExceptionMapper is used for some specific Exceptions such as `ExceptionMapper<IllegalArgumentException>` instead of catching all exceptions as shown above in the code `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` or simply return the response as shown in the code below:

```
 if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {
    WebApplicationException webApplicationException = (WebApplicationException) exception;
    return webApplicationException.getResponse();
}
```

The serialization error will not occur. Why? because the framework takes care of this (based on `@Produces` annotation it will serialize the response for **NON** WebApplicationException based responses. And for `WebApplicationException` based response as shown above, framework will take care of the response as well (since ErrorResponse entity was never used)

However coming to the problem mentioned in this ticket. `NotAllowedException` occurs in the spec implementation code **before** the method associated with URI gets executed. Thus the `@Produces` annotation doesn't take effect and while Marshalling the response, a default MediaType octet-stream is used.

```
resteasy-jaxrs:3.1.0.Final
class: SegmentNode
method: public Match match(List<Match> matches, String httpMethod, HttpRequest request)
```

So while the following exceptions occur;
DefaultOptionsMethodException
NotAllowedException
NotSupportedException
NotAcceptableException

request attribute `RESTEASY_CHOSEN_ACCEPT` doesn't get set

```
  request.setAttribute(RESTEASY_CHOSEN_ACCEPT, sortEntry.getAcceptType());
  return sortEntry.match;
```

and when the server tries to write a response it doesn't find the MediaType (as we never set it while creating a response object)

```
resteasy-jaxrs:3.1.0.Final
class: ServerResponseWriter
method: public static void writeNomapResponse(BuiltResponse jaxrsResponse, final HttpRequest request, ...

 if (jaxrsResponse.getEntity() != null && jaxrsResponse.getMediaType() == null) {
     setDefaultContentType(request, jaxrsResponse, providerFactory, method);
 }
```

It tries to set it from method annotations; which as mentioned before were never set, since the `NotAllowedException` occurred before `RESTEASY_CHOSEN_ACCEPT` could have been set.

It finds a wild card as no accept headers were specified and thus octet stream was set

```
resteasy-jaxrs:3.1.0.Final
class: ServerResponseWriter
method: protected static void setDefaultContentType(HttpRequest request, BuiltResponse ...
if (chosen.isWildcardType()) {
     chosen = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE;
}
```

(*this a just a summary; for detailed steps I must go back to the spec implementation code*)

Thus I must specify a mediatype. This can done looking at the `HttpHeaders` from `@Context` to make it dynamic or if nothing is specified in the headers as in my case, I provide a default MediaType `Application/XML` for serialization to proceed.

Hope this helps someone also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the appropriate format returned by your `ExceptionMapper` using the `HttpHeaders` of JAX-RS API and get the `MediaType` of the request entity, cf the javadoc : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getMediaType--

So your code would be as follow :

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Context
    private HttpHeaders m_headers;

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericExceptionMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(exception.getClass().getSimpleName(), exception.getMessage());

        if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {
            LOG.error("Type: {}", exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
            LOG.error("Message: {}", exception.getMessage());
            WebApplicationException webApplicationException = (WebApplicationException) exception;
            return Response.status(webApplicationException.getResponse().getStatus()).entity(errorResponse).build();
        }

        return Response.serverError().entity(errorResponse).type(m_headers.getMediaType()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your response. I happen to debug the implementation of RestEasy spec to understand the problem.

Comment: Your solution only work when ContentType is set in the request headers. This means, I need to explicitly specify the client that ALWAYS specify the content type.

Notice if an exception is thrown from your Resource; you don't need to specify mediatype while constructing a response object. The reason is that if no Content Types are specified in the request, the annotation "Produces" is enough to find the MessageBodyWriter for marshalling; however NotAllowedException is special

Comment: In this case you might get the Acceptable media Type through m_headers.getAcceptableMediaTypes(). Take a look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227360/jax-rs-jersey-custom-exception-with-xml-or-json